# koala get likes on post

Tags: ruby-on-rails, facebook-graph-api, haml, koala

i am currently using the koala, and all seems to be working, though when attempting to use the following to gain the likes on a certain posts all i seem to be getting is the array of items

code within application helper

```
    def facebook
    @facebook ||= Koala::Facebook::API.new(current_user.oauth_token)
    block_given? ? yield(@facebook) : @facebook
  rescue Koala::Facebook::APIError
    logger.info e.to_s
    nil
  end

def likes_count obj
    facebook.get_object(obj, :fields => "likes.summary(true)")
  end
```

code within view

```
=likes_count(feed['id'])
```

results returned

```
{"id"=>"846011512095715", "updated_time"=>"2014-06-22T11:11:45+0000", "likes"=>{"data"=>[{"id"=>"10152444475716893", "name"=>"Tahlia Fulton"}, {"id"=>"10152240895519022", "name"=>"Tim Raftery"}, {"id"=>"481256765338477", "name"=>"Gabby Taylor"}, {"id"=>"664803753573900", "name"=>"Harriet Ochsenbein"}, {"id"=>"10152453604228810", "name"=>"Kelly Jenkinson"}, {"id"=>"10152145864189249", "name"=>"David Glazzard"}, {"id"=>"10203193488711772", "name"=>"Bianca Love"}, {"id"=>"10152567265688833", "name"=>"Clare Duncan"}, {"id"=>"105513176145556", "name"=>"Frankston Hockey Club"}], "paging"=>{"cursors"=>{"after"=>"MTA1NTEzMTc2MTQ1NTU2", "before"=>"MTAxNTI0NDQ0NzU3MTY4OTM="}}, "summary"=>{"total_count"=>9}}}
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Likes on a post:

```
likes = @graph.get_object('post_id', :fields => "likes.summary(true)")["likes"]["summary"]["total_count"]
```

In case anyone comes across this and also happens to be looking for the shares and comments count:

Shares on a post:

```
shares = @graph.get_object('post_id', :fields => "shares")["shares"]["count"]
```

Comments on a post:

```
comments = @graph.get_object('post_id', :fields => "comments.summary(true)")["comments"]["summary"]["total_count"]
```

Or if you prefer a hash of all three:

```
post_kpis = @graph.get_connections(@post, 'insights', metric: 'post_storytellers_by_action_type').first["values"].first["value"]
```

To get all the insights on your post:

```
post_insights = @graph.get_connections(@post, 'insights')
```

Comment: Hash of all 3, and insights doesn't seem to work anymore.  Can get the same results with: `graph.get_object(post_id, :fields => "shares,likes.summary(true),comments.summary(true)")`

Answer (score 0):

Try `@graph.get_connections(post_id, "likes")` to expose a `Koala::Facebook::API::GraphCollection` object on which you can call `.next_page` to traverse the entire list of likes.